Stat Totals of Artifice Armor From Different Sources
After obtaining a 4x100 stat build, I wanted to help a friend do something similar.
What are the distributions of stat totals for artifice armor across different sources in the game? So, if for example you play a master level dungeon, given 50 armor pieces, how many will have 66, 67 or 68 stat totals? Is it better in specific dungeons? The sources of artifice armor at the moment are master dungeons, the crucible competitive playlist, and master worked exotics can be converted to artifice using an exotic cypher.
-Note 1: The reason I assume the distributions are different is because the max base stat artifice armor that I have received from competitive crucible is 63, while from master dungeons I have gotten a 68 stat, multiple 67s, and many 66-stat artifice armors.
-Note 2: The artifice class items give no base stats and are only helpful when the first is obtained. For those reasons, for the purposes of this question they can be considered a 68 for the first instance, but a 0 for all other instances.
-Note 3: I will try my best to figure out this data if nobody else has it, as I need to farm artifice anyway. I will post any relevant data as an answer if that is the case.

I thought artifice armour just had the extra mod slot for the +3 mods

@Neon1024 They have that in addition to the basic stats that all other armors have. Bungie somewhat recently nerfed the high base stats on artifice armor, and thus I would like to know where the best farming location is. Artifice armor is extremely powerful because it can utilize both the +3 mod and also the up to 68 base stats at the same time. This means you can combine them to have 4 pieces of 71 stat armor before master working or stat mods. With masterwork and stat mods, you can have 4 pieces of armor with 93 stats. This makes 4x100 builds far easier.

I have started my research into stat distributions of artifice armor from the following activities: competitive crucible, master duality, master spire of the watcher, master ghosts of the deep, master warlord's ruin, master grasp of avarice. Due to my PvP incompetence this WILL take some time.
